# (S/D)NAT over NF hooks

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, netfilter

Could someone help on explaining the advantage of iptables NAT over the netfilter hooks. Say suppose, instead of using NAT if we create custom kernel module to bind handler with netfilter for PRE/POST mangling, then in general which method (NAT/NF) is more optimized or regulated one ?

Any links or pointers will be helpful.

Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

According to netfilter documentations:

```
    Netfilter is merely a series of hooks in various points in a protocol stack (at this stage, IPv4, IPv6 and DECnet). The (idealized) IPv4 traversal diagram looks like the following:

        A Packet Traversing the Netfilter System:

           --->[1]--->[ROUTE]--->[3]--->[4]--->
                         |            ^
                         |            |
                         |         [ROUTE]
                         v            |
                        [2]          [5]
                         |            ^
                         |            |
                         v            |

    On the left is where packets come in: having passed the simple sanity checks (i.e., not truncated, IP checksum OK, not a promiscuous receive), they are passed to the netfilter framework's NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING [1] hook.
Next they enter the routing code, which decides whether the packet is destined for another interface, or a local process. The routing code may drop packets that are unroutable.
If it's destined for the box itself, the netfilter framework is called again for the NF_IP_LOCAL_IN [2] hook, before being passed to the process (if any).
If it's destined to pass to another interface instead, the netfilter framework is called for the NF_IP_FORWARD [3] hook.
The packet then passes a final netfilter hook, the NF_IP_POST_ROUTING [4] hook, before being put on the wire again.
The NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT [5] hook is called for packets that are created locally. Here you can see that routing occurs after this hook is called: in fact, the routing code is called first (to figure out the source IP address and some IP options): if you want to alter the routing, you must alter the `skb->dst' field yourself, as is done in the NAT code.
```

And :

```
NAT

This is the realm of the `nat' table, which is fed packets from two netfilter hooks: for non-local packets, the NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING and NF_IP_POST_ROUTING hooks are perfect for destination and source alterations respectively. If CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_LOCAL is defined, the hooks NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT and NF_IP_LOCAL_IN are used for altering the destination of local packets.

This table is slightly different from the `filter' table, in that only the first packet of a new connection will traverse the table: the result of this traversal is then applied to all future packets in the same connection.
Masquerading, Port Forwarding, Transparent Proxying

I divide NAT into Source NAT (where the first packet has its source altered), and Destination NAT (the first packet has its destination altered).

Masquerading is a special form of Source NAT: port forwarding and transparent proxying are special forms of Destination NAT. These are now all done using the NAT framework, rather than being independent entities.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick prompt. Can you please clarify this statement bit more ? "where the first packet has its source altered" Does this mean, the second packet will not have its source modified by means of software or something else will happen ? Hardware/netwrok layer contribution? Look up/FWT ? Any links will be helpful . Thanks.